# AES-256: IV vector misunderstanding between Ruby and Java implementations

Tags: java, ruby, encryption, aes, initialization-vector

I have "inherited" a Ruby on Rails app, and I must translate this app from Ruby to Java, and the most important thing, I don't have contact with the creator.

My problem is with the IV vector in AES-256 authentication. Ruby app uses AESCrypt gem to encrypt and decrypt user's password. It works fine, and I have already some thousands of users in DB.

The problem is when I try to do the same in Java (I've already updated JCE to allow 256bit key lenght). The Key and the IV are writen as binary strings in ruby source code (see bellow), and when I try to use it in Java I get a exception which say that the IV lenght must be 16 bytes long (I know that it must be 16 bytes long, but the binary string in Ruby has 32 characters).

Ruby code (works fine):

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/md5'
require 'base64'

module AESCrypt
  KEY   = "AB1CD237690AF13B6721AD237A"
  IV    = "por874hyufijdue7w63ysxwet4320o90"
  TYPE  = "AES-256-CBC"

  def AESCrypt.key(key)
    key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(key)
    key.slice(0..32)
  end

# Encrypts a block of data given an encryption key and an 
  # initialization vector (iv).  Keys, iv's, and the data returned 
  # are all binary strings.  Cipher_type should be "AES-256-CBC",
  # "AES-256-ECB", or any of the cipher types supported by OpenSSL.  
  # Pass nil for the iv if the encryption type doesn't use iv's (like
  # ECB).
  #:return: => String
  #:arg: data => String 
  #:arg: key => String
  #:arg: iv => String
  #:arg: cipher_type => String  
  def AESCrypt.encrypt(data)
    return nil if data.nil?
    return data if data.blank?
    aes = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new(TYPE)
    aes.encrypt
    aes.key = AESCrypt.key(KEY)
    aes.iv = IV if IV != nil
    result = aes.update(data) + aes.final
    Base64.encode64(result)
  end
end
```

and this is my Java code (it should do the same, seems that works with a 16 chars/bytes IV):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            String KEY = "AB1CD237690AF13B6721AD237A";
            String IV = "por874hyufijdue7w63ysxwet4320o90";
            SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(KEY);
            String message = "password";

            final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes());
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
            byte[] ciphedText = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
            String encoded = Base64.encodeBase64String(ciphedText);

            System.out.println("ENCRYPTED text= " + encoded);
}

public  static SecretKeySpec generateKey(final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        byte[] key = digest.digest();       
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        return secretKeySpec;
    }
```

And I'm getting this exception (obviously):

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Wrong IV length: must be 16 bytes long
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.init(CipherCore.java:516)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineInit(AESCipher.java:339)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.implInit(Cipher.java:801)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:859)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1370)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1301)
    at com.javi.test.security.Test.main(Test.java:129)
```

I guess my problem is the way I convert the IV java string in byte[]. I think that openSSL code in ruby is unpacking (or doing something internally) the 32 bytes of the IV to 16 bytes. I have tried a lot of things, but I'm going crazy.

Anyone had the same problem or figure out where could be my problem?
I have posted the encryption code but I hace the same issue with decryption.

Thanks in advance, I'll be very grateful with every answer. :)

Comment: I don't know how ruby/openssl operate, but probably only the first 16 characters are silently used for the IV.

Comment: I've just done a test taking in account only the fist 16 chars of my IV string. The text I encrypt is "123456", the encrypted text by ruby app is "APkjtkW8yg4ibXhc/OgO3w==" and the encrypted text by java is "n6ZD4972iputzGCstjifXw==". They don't match each other :( Maybe the earlier KEY generation is not working at it should, I'm new with encryption. Thanks anyway @ArtjomB.

Comment: Are you encoding a UTF-8 string in the Ruby code?  Because Java is UTF-8 by default, and a UTF-8 string will encode differently to a ASCII / Latin string.

Comment: I think that all the ruby app is using UTF-8. I have this in my Application ruby class: config.encoding = "utf-8"

Answer (score 1):

First, your IV is not actually iv, IV should be HEX encoded, but you have ASCII string "por874hyufijdue7w63ysxwet4320o90", may be it is some how encoded?

Second, IV.getBytes() will transofr IV's each character to hex encoding like p = 0x70, o = 0x6F, r = 0x72, etc...

It is not a useful answer, but may be hint.

Actually IV must be the same length as block cipher single block length. You have 32 bytes long IV itself, if you make IV.getBytes() IV length should match the cipher block length

Comment: You are close. The problem is the key, it should be 32 bytes long, not 26 bytes as "AB1CD237690AF13B6721AD237A", the rest of this key is undefined, it won't reproduce the same cipher. It's okay if key or IV is too long. For testing, it's okay to use ASCII values as long as it has the minimum length.

Comment: Hi @Barmak, you are right, I have changed the MD5 digest of the key to this: Key = DigestUtils.md5Hex(KEY).getBytes(); of apache_commons_codec and then it has 32 bytes. I think that I've fixed that, but I still have the problem of the IV length.  Juris, I know that my IV is weird and its length is 32 bytes. Are Ruby doing something to transform these 32 to 16 bytes?

Comment: @Javier, I don't know Ruby and MD5, I thought MD5 returns 128bit (16 bytes) key. Just use ASCII value for testing, make the key 32 characters long. IV 16 characters. Message 16 characters long (to avoid padding). Lets see if that works for testing.

Comment: @Barmak, I've just tested my code with 32 char key, 16 char IV and 16 char message, and it works fine. It encrypts de message and it decrypts it. So I think is something with my KEY or IV. Thanks for your help :)